# Set CASE statement to variable and then use that variable in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I am using SQL Server 2008 and have a very large CASE statement that is also used in the GROUP By clause.  I would like to set the CASE statement to a variable in order to minimize code maintenance and maximize reuse.  The problem is that I get this error:

```
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
```

This CASED column is not the only column referenced in the GROUP By clause so I'm not sure why I get this error.

I've searched the site but didn't find a problem quite like mine (surprisingly).  So, how do I go about getting around this?

UPDATE:  I have included the DB type.  As far as adding the code for what I have, I'm not sure that would add anything but bulk as it is over 200 lines.  It's not a complex statement at all.  It just takes various country codes and maps them to their full country names.  For instance, the U.S. has over 50 codes so I am using the CASE statement to consolidate them.  This allows me to group my info by country.

Comment: In SQL Server you could wrap the logic in a user defined function.

Comment: Why don't you want to put your country codes in a table?

Comment: I am not the primary DBA and can only create temp tables at this point.

Comment: Mayo, thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I have pretty limited access to the db at this time and can't do everything I would like.  If that changes, I will definitely look into the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a subquery:

```
select var, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (case <nasty expressions go here>
              end) var
      from t
     ) t
group by var
```

The error that you are getting is because the variables in the `group by` is a constant.  I'm not sure why the error message is not clearer.

And, in the event that you actually do want to include a constant in the `group by` for some reason (as I have had occasion to do), then a column helps:

```
group by (case when coalesce(col, '') = coalesce(col, '') then 'some constant' end)
```

At least in SQL Server 2008, the engine does not recognize the expression as a constant.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this out and will let you know the results.

Comment: Gordon, this works and definitely reduces my code greatly.  Thanks!  At some point the future I hope to create a function or something I can reuse globally so I don't have to keep copying and pasting this code for each of my scripts.

Comment: @N1tr0 . . . If the `case` logic is all from a single table, you might be interested in computed columns (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx).  Alternatively, create a view and use the view in all of your logic.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  I'll have to look into those alternatives.